# What are all the sources of XP?

Tags: pokemon-go

As the title suggests, what are all the possible sources of XP on PokemonGo? I just manually evolved a Kakuna into a Beedril last night, and got 1000 XP for that, which has never happened to me before. Obviously there could still be other sources that I do not know about.

So, what are all possible ways to get XP?

Comment: One of the best thing you can do to get a large amount of XP is to wait for evolves your pokemon. When you get a large amount of candy of  Weedle/Caterpie/Pidgey(for exemple 100) you use a Lucky Egg and evolves your pokemon !

Comment: Probably a bunch of `.cpp` files on a Microsoft server.

Comment: @TobiaTesan what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: That's where the sources for (Windows) XP probably are. Sorry. Terrible pun.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are several ways to get XP in the game. I've copied this from the [Pokemon GO Wiki.](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Experience)

- Win a fight with a pokemon at at an opposing team's gym: 150 XP
- Fighting a pokemon at an opposing team's gym: 100 XP
- Win a fight with a Pokemon at a gym that belongs to your team: 50 XP
- Capturing Pokemon (100 XP)
- Adding new Pokemon to your Pokedex, whether seen, caught, or evolved (500 XP)
- Evolving Pokemon (500 XP)
- Going to Pokestops (50 XP)
- Hatching an egg (500 XP for new Pokemon or 200XP for existing)
- Capturing a Pokemon with a Nice Throw (10 XP bonus) OR
- Capturing a Pokemon with a Great Throw (50 XP bonus) OR
- Capturing a Pokemon with an Excellent Throw (100 XP bonus) OR
- Capturing a Pokemon with an Curve ball (10 XP bonus)

All of these can be doubled by using the [Lucky Egg](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Lucky_Egg) item

Comment: Note that the eggs will give you differing amounts of experience based on how many KM it took to hatch it

Comment: Sometimes I seem to get 100 XP or 150 XP from a pokestop for no apparent reason.

Comment: Evolving Pokemon can be worth more than 500 XP without the use of a Lucky Egg. I evolved an Eevee into a 850 CP Vaporeon and got 1000 XP for it. I'm trainer level 14.

Comment: I think hatching gives 200 exp for pokemon you already had before. (atleast my rattata did)

Comment: Hatching always gives 200XP and an extra 500XP if the hatched Pokémon  was not yet registered in your Pokédex. Just confirmed by hatching my first Pikachu, I got 700XP

Comment: Yesterday I won a battle against 1 out of 3 pokemon at a friendly gym, and received <25exp (19, I think). I've seen no evidence that you get 50exp for winning these fights.

Comment: Don't you also get a small amount of experience for achieving a medal?

Comment: I recently noticed that hatching eggs gives me 1000XP, even when a new Pokémon would be obtained this way I expected the XP gain to be 700 (200 + 500). Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: @Anzeo I read somewhere that exp for eggs is based on the distance it takes to hatch it. 200, 500, and 1000 exp for 2km, 5km, and 10km eggs. I haven't confirmed that yet though.

Comment: @SnoringFrog thanks, but I don't think that's correct. I thought it used to be: 200XP for hatching the egg (regardless of distance) and +500XP if the hatchling was not yet registered to the Pokédex. The 2 eggs I have hatched netting me 1000 XP each were IIRC 5km ones

Comment: 100xp per km for eggs. (200xp for 2km, 500xp for 5km, 1000xp for 10km) Pokestops that give 6 or more items also reward 100xp instead of 50xp.

Comment: @Ellesedil you get an additional 500xp for adding it to your pokedex.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an exhaustive list with the exact XP values:

- Catching a pokemon: 100 XP
- Adding a new pokemon to the pokedex: 500 XP
- Evolving a pokemon: 500 XP
- Curve ball: 10 XP
- "Nice" throw: 10 XP
- "Great" throw: 50 XP
- "Excellent" throw: 100 XP
- Visit a Pokestop: 50 XP
- Hatch an egg: 200 XP
- Beating a pokemon at a gym: 150 XP
- Battling a pokemon at a gym: 100 XP
- Beat a pokemon in training at a gym: 50 XP

It's worth noting that using a special egg will double these XP values for the next 30 minutes.

Comment: How can we have a nice, great, excellent and curve throw?

Comment: You can't.  You might be able to get a curve throw and one of the others, but I can't get even a "Nice" throw consistently, so good luck.  The "Excellent" and "Great" throws are just better versions of the "Nice" throw.

Comment: Unfortunately only one can be applied Wires77; no Curve + Nice/Great/Excellent throws. A throw might have multiple qualities, but only one bonus will be rewarded.

Also, I thought evolving was 500 XP?

Comment: I can throw curve balls by spinning the ball at the bottom of the screen before throwing it. Depending on how you swipe, you can curve it a lot more easily.

Comment: Evolving a pokemon is +500, not +100.  I tried to edit it but it's not large enough of a change for the site to allow

Comment: Oops, fixed the evolve XP.  And that makes sense @Ekmod, I just suck at  throwing sometimes so I wasn't sure if someone else could do it.

Comment: To be fair @Wires77, I've heard that the Nice/Great/Excellent recognition is a little buggy (I think the same with Curve, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ).

Comment: Note that the eggs will give you differing amounts of experience based on how many KM it took to hatch it

Comment: Excellent is Nice/Great + Curve. There's no way to get an excellent without curving

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list (not exhaustive though):

1. Evolution
2. Catching a Pokemon
3. Catching a new Pokemon (for discovery)
4. Nice throw, great throw and curve throw
5. Visit a Pokestop
6. Visit a gym
7. Hatch an egg

Answer (score 0):

Complete List :

- Visit Pokestop    50
- Catch Pokemon 100
- Catch New Pokemon 500
- Nice Throw    10
- Great Throw   50
- Excellent Throw   100
- Hatch Pokemon 200
- Evolve a Pokemon  500
- Defeat Pokemon Training   10
- Defeat Enemy Pokemon  100
- Defeat All Enemy Pokemon 50